# How do you use the preprocessor to conditionally declare the superclass of a new class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macos, oop

I have a framework I need to rewrite partially, and am adopting AFNetworking. Because of this, version two needs to be of a different superclass(AFHTTPClient). I'm trying to have a preprocessor flag and conditionally declare this.

Here's my code:

```
#define TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION 2

#if TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION == 1
@interface TKSession : NSObject
#elif TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION == 2
@interface TKSession : AFHTTPClient
#endif
{
@private
    NSMutableArray  *_cachedShifts;
}
```

The compiler(clang) gives an error, basically stating that the declaration is not being read properly by the compiler after preprocessing. It thinks it's seeing this:

```
#define TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION 2

{
@private
    NSMutableArray  *_cachedShifts;
}
...
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: The `@end` is missing after the interface declaration. Apart from that, it should work.

Comment: I have that. Left it out of the code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION 2

#if TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION == 1
@interface TKSession : NSObject
#else
@interface TKSession : AFHTTPClient
#endif
{
@private
     NSMutableArray  *_cachedShifts;
}
```

but better define someting like that:

```
#if TLC_FRAMEWORK_VERSION == 1
typedef NSObject TLCHTTPClient;
#else
typedef AFHTTPClient TLCHTTPClient;
#endif

@interface TKSession : TLCHTTPClient
{
@private
     NSMutableArray  *_cachedShifts;
}
```

easier to read

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I will answer my own question. This was a scope issue where the header I was importing with that flag was for some reason not being parsed properly. I'm too busy to fark around with compiler issues or exceptions, so I'm declaring the flag locally.

Comment: "I'm too busy to fark around with compiler issues or exceptions[...]": I highly recommend to trace these issues down and solve them. Otherwise you might suffer from strange, compile time generated erroneous behavior. Usually this kind of problem comes from circular include dependencies...